# Getting a syntax error with argsort

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to run the following code but am getting a syntax error. I cannot see what am I doing wrong with the argsort?  I am using python 3.

```
def display_topics(H, W, feature_names, documents, no_top_words, no_top_documents):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(H):
        print ("Topic %d:" % (topic_idx))
        print (" ".join([feature_names[i]
                        for i in topic.argsort()[:-no_top_words - 1:-1]])
        top_doc_indices = np.argsort(W[:,topic_idx])[::-1][0:no_top_documents]
        for doc_index in top_doc_indices:
            print (documents[doc_index])
```

I get the following error on the specified line:

```
File "<ipython-input-42-1ad798bb95c3>", line 6
    top_doc_indices = np.argsort(W[:,topic_idx]),[::-1],[0:no_top_documents]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: When you get a syntax error on a line that looks perfectly fine, often the problem is the line above it is missing a `)`, `]`, or `}`, so the parser is looking for the rest of that expression.

Comment: @excaza Are you confusing the OP’s multiline list comprehension with a separate statement, or an I just missing something viewing this in mobile?

Comment: you're missing a `)` in the line above it for the print statement

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy